# Formatting Bootstrap Carousel Layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the bootstrap carousel to display with the control arrows either side of the carousel, as by default they overlap into the images.

Here is an example of where i'm up to : http://jsfiddle.net/LHAB8/

Ideally i'd like it to look like

[Left Arrow] [Carousel with 4 boxes showing at a time] [Right Arrow]

```
<div class="span2">
   <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
</div>
<div class="carousel slide span8" id="myCarousel">
    ...
</div>
<div class="span2">
   <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
</div>
```

but i can't get the positoning using bootstraps grid system to look right - the layout does not need to be responsive.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You should edit the bootstrap css to get what you want...
I rather prefer the bxslider.com, responsive and easy customizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add padding on the div.carousel

```
.carousel
{
    padding:10px 70px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LHAB8/1/

Answer (score 0):

To do this hack, you can modify the bootstrap css or add this :

**Html**

```
<a href="my-control left">Left</a>
<a href="my-control right">Right</a>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.carousel-control').hide();
$('.my-control').click(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass('left'))
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('prev');
    else if($(this).hasClass('right'))
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');
});
```

Check [Bootstrap Docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel) for more events